# Cisco AnyConnect VPN Client drops

Tags: vpn, cisco, cisco-vpn, anyconnect

I have the Cisco AnyConnect VPN client on a Server2003 std edition.  The client will periodically drop and I have to go in and manually reconnect it.  Is there a way with to restart the client and pass it the username and password so that it connects automatically?

Many Thanks

Comment: I was able to use a vbs script and the sendkeys function to pass credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Using VBS scripting might be a good option in this case.